Casting a number from one type to another: the trait bound `usize: From<u32>` is not satisfied
I have a function that gets the dimensions of an image, and in different scenarios, I would it to be cast from a u32 to another number type suchas usize, i32, etc. However, when I try to do the following in get_dimensions it doesn't work. Is something like this possible? I looked at How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically? but in that example it uses an explicit type such as i32::from(...) whereas I would hopefully like to use a dynamic type.
Rust Playground Example
struct Example {
    width: u32,
    height: u32
}

impl Example {
    pub fn get_dimensions<T>(&self) -> (T, T)
    where
        T: From<u32>,
    {
        (T::from(self.width), T::from(self.height))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let example = Example { width: 800, height: 600 };
    let dimensions = example.get_dimensions::<usize>();
    println!("{dimensions}");
}

The error message I receive:
the trait bound `usize: From<u32>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
  `usize` implements `From<bool>`
  `usize` implements `From<std::ptr::Alignment>`
  `usize` implements `From<u16>`
  `usize` implements `From<u8>`


If only integers are involved, you can use TryFrom.

It should always be integers, so I tried (T::try_from(self.width).unwrap(), T::try_from(self.height).unwrap()) which results in the same error.

You need to change the bound to T: TryFrom<u32>.

That looks like it works, where my where seems to need to look like this: where     T: TryFrom<u32>,     <T as TryFrom<u32>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug,

Since rust also some targets with pointer width less than 32, it does not implement usize: From<u32> as usize is the pointer width of the target, i.e. 32-bit in 32-bit systems and 64-bit in 64-bit systems.
To use dynamic types which can be converted to u32 fallibly, you need to use TryFrom<u32>. So the code would be like so:
struct Example {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Example {
    // Since this returns a `Result` you need to update your code to handle failures
    pub fn get_dimensions<T>(&self) -> Result<(T, T), <T as TryFrom<u32>>::Error>
    where
        T: TryFrom<u32>,
    {
        Ok((T::try_from(self.width)?, T::try_from(self.height)?))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let example = Example {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
    };
    let dimensions = example.get_dimensions::<usize>().unwrap(); // Unwrapping for simplicity
    println!("{dimensions:?}");
}

